# Passing value to a function properly with Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, function, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

So quick one which I'm stumped on.

Looking to show a popup in my Appcelerator app, which works fine, but I can't seem to get and pass the variable to my function, as it keeps coming back as undefined.

The popup code snippet isn't posted here as that isn't the issue.

Probably a complete schoolboy error here, anyone able to point out what I've done wrong?

So I need to pass "ourscreenName" and "ourscreenURL" into the showOurscreenBooking function when the user taps on a PosterView (which are created on the fly via the HTTP request).

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload: function() {
                // Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

                json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                Ti.API.info(json);
                for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                    posterView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                        width: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth / 3,
                        defaultImage: 'images/imgloader.png',
                        top: 0,
                        backgroundColor: '#000'
                    });

                    getPoster(json[i].tmdb_id, posterView, json[i].ourscreen_film_name);

                    ourscreenName = json[i].ourscreen_film_name;
                    ourscreenURL = json[i].ourscreen_url;

                    scrollView.add(posterView);

                    posterView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        // need to open up the booking popup
                        showOurscreenBooking(e.ourscreenName, e.ourscreenURL);
                    });

                }

            },
            onerror: function(e) {
                Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
                Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
                Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
                alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data in event loop. Try again.');


            },
            timeout: 30000 // add longer timeout for slower connections
        });
```

Thanks!

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't consider this a best practice (I really need a shot of fresh air after a long working day), but what you could do is:

```
getPoster(json[i].tmdb_id, posterView, json[i].ourscreen_film_name);

ourscreenName = json[i].ourscreen_film_name;
ourscreenURL = json[i].ourscreen_url;

// add your properties as custom properties to the view
posterView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  width: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth / 3,
  defaultImage: 'images/imgloader.png',
  top: 0,
  backgroundColor: '#000',
  ourscreenName: ourscreenName,
  ourscreenUrl: ourscreenUrl
});

scrollView.add(posterView);

posterView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  showOurscreenBooking(e.source.ourscreenName, e.source.ourscreenURL);
});
```

Also see https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/12111/event-propagation----how-to-use-eventsource-property

Comment: That's it! I just have a slight issue where if you click the first poster you get normal behaviour. If you click a second poster you get the first poster info and then the second. If you click a third, you then get the 1st, 2nd and 3rd poster info.

Comment: My first thought: make it 'var posterView = Ti.UI.createImageView...' instead just posterView, you have probably defined posterView as global, and let me know if it solves your problem.